# calculating top 10 products for a given query based on its priority in python

Tags: python, pandas

suppose we are given a dataframe like:

```
                       Query  Productid  priority
index
0                        3ds    2125233  0.018946
1                        rca    2009324  0.027599
2                       nook    1517163  0.009443
3                        rca    2877125  0.012054
4                        rca    2877134  0.005557
5              flatscreentvs    2416092  0.011961
6                    macbook    3108172  0.010459
7                        3ds    2264036  0.165948
8                        rca    8280834  0.004006
9                 memorycard    2740208  0.013744
10               acpowercord    2584273  0.006865
11                zaggiphone    1230537  0.136073
12            watchthethrone    3168067  0.104679
13     remotecontrolextender    7997055  0.113058
14                 camcorder    2009041  0.017809
15                       3ds    1988047  0.031711
16                       3ds    1686079  0.043783
17        wirelessheadphones    3770439  0.014714
18        wirelessheadphones    2602403  0.008525
19                 samsung40    2126065  0.018066
```

i want to  find top 2 `product_ids` on the basis of priority with respect to a given query.

for eg. if we have `query=3ds` then top 2 products should be:

```
1. 1988047 
2. 1686079
```

Comment: Hi @neha welcome to SO ... 1) format your question 2) you need to show what you have done. SO is not a code outsourcing factory...

Comment: Can you explain more your output? Do you need find 2 `Productid` where `priority` is `maximal`?

Comment: I need to find best product for a given query.
So, I assigned priority to the query, product pair using which I want to find two products with highest priority given a query.

Comment: @neha - please see my and MaxU answer, I am still little confused. For me return in `Query=3ds` output `2264036` and `1686079`, because top priorities are `0.165948` and `0.043783` in all rows with `Query=3ds`. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an equivalent for Oracle's [row_number()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions170.htm#SQLRF06100) analytic function:

```
In [172]: df.assign(rn=df.sort_values('priority', ascending=0).groupby('Query').cumcount() + 1).query('rn < 3').sort_values(['Query','rn'])
Out[172]:
                       Query  Productid  priority  rn
index
7                        3ds    2264036  0.165948   1
16                       3ds    1686079  0.043783   2
10               acpowercord    2584273  0.006865   1
14                 camcorder    2009041  0.017809   1
5              flatscreentvs    2416092  0.011961   1
6                    macbook    3108172  0.010459   1
9                 memorycard    2740208  0.013744   1
2                       nook    1517163  0.009443   1
1                        rca    2009324  0.027599   1
3                        rca    2877125  0.012054   2
13     remotecontrolextender    7997055  0.113058   1
19                 samsung40    2126065  0.018066   1
12            watchthethrone    3168067  0.104679   1
17        wirelessheadphones    3770439  0.014714   1
18        wirelessheadphones    2602403  0.008525   2
11                zaggiphone    1230537  0.136073   1
```

show `Productid` for selected `Query`:

```
In [180]: (df.assign(rn=df.sort_values('priority', ascending=0).groupby('Query').cumcount() + 1)
   .....:    .query('Query=="3ds" and rn < 3')['Productid']
   .....: )
Out[180]:
index
7     2264036
16    1686079
Name: Productid, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @neha, did it help?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot for this.
Now what should we do to fetch two top most ranked products on the basis of given query. for eg- if we search for '3ds' then it should show only -
2264036
1686079

Comment: @neha, please see update in my answer

Comment: yes it is working exactly like i wanted. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
print (df.set_index('Productid').groupby('Query')['priority'].nlargest(2).reset_index())
                    Query  Productid  priority
0                     3ds    2264036  0.165948
1                     3ds    1686079  0.043783
2             acpowercord    2584273  0.006865
3               camcorder    2009041  0.017809
4           flatscreentvs    2416092  0.011961
5                 macbook    3108172  0.010459
6              memorycard    2740208  0.013744
7                    nook    1517163  0.009443
8                     rca    2009324  0.027599
9                     rca    2877125  0.012054
10  remotecontrolextender    7997055  0.113058
11              samsung40    2126065  0.018066
12         watchthethrone    3168067  0.104679
13     wirelessheadphones    3770439  0.014714
14     wirelessheadphones    2602403  0.008525
15             zaggiphone    1230537  0.136073
```

Comment: wow! ++ for your speed! :)

Comment: but output is different, maybe your solution is what OP want.

Comment: can we assign a rank to each product entry with respect to individual query and then by giving a particular query we can find top 2 product_id based on their ranks ? Just like in a recommendation system gives you top 2 products based on your search query.

Comment: Hmmm, then it looks like need [`MaxU solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38630059/2901002).